# Clickhouse materialized view deduplication keeping latest record

Tags: sql, database, bigdata, clickhouse, materialized-views

I have a materialized view of some google ad assets with labels, the labels could change each day and each ad asset's status in a day corresponds to a row in the database, I tried to make a materialized view such as this to store just the latest label of each asset but doesn't seem to handle deduplication very well, since our new data gets added daily at a certain time I can schedule an optimize table command each morning, but it doesn't seem to keep the latest record by date.

The materialized view is created as such:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW creative_asset.google_ad_group_ad_asset_label_mv_test
(

    `assetId` Int64,
    `performanceLabel` String,
    `approvalStatus` String,
    `reviewStatus` String,
    `date` String
)
ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree
ORDER BY assetId
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192 
POPULATE
AS
SELECT
    gagaav.assetId,
    gagaav.assetPerformanceLabel AS performanceLabel,
    gagaav.assetApprovalStatus AS approvalStatus,
    gagaav.assetReviewStatus AS reviewStatus,
    gagaav.`date` AS `date`
FROM 
    creative_asset.google_ad_group_ad_asset_view AS gagaav
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT
            assetId,
            max(date) AS maxDate
        FROM creative_asset.google_ad_group_ad_asset_view AS gagaav
        GROUP BY gagaav.assetId
    ) AS maxDate ON (maxDate.assetId = creative_asset.google_ad_group_ad_asset_view.assetId) AND (gagaav.date = maxDate.maxDate)
GROUP BY gagaav.assetId, gagaav.`date`
```

Is there a viable way to eliminate duplicates while keeping only the latest by date or is it only possible to deduplicate in the query?

Answer (score 2):

```
FROM 
    creative_asset.google_ad_group_ad_asset_view 
INNER JOIN 
   ( FROM creative_asset.google_ad_group_ad_asset_view AS gagaav )
```

In both occurrences MATERIALIZED VIEW sees data from the current insert.

ClickHouse MATERIALIZED VIEW never reads a source table.
https://den-crane.github.io/Everything_you_should_know_about_materialized_views_commented.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much! 
From what I read I understand that what I did only works for the first populate since that's the only time the source table is read is that correct?
Since our application is not time sensitive does not need to be always updated in real time would it be a viable solution to schedule something like a populate every morning and is there away to do that?